# JWT Token Not Specific to User

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, express-jwt

In my **NodeJs (express +MongoDB)** ,I'm using JWT Token to allow user routes such as Change Password , Update User ..

However, the JWT Token given is not specific to one user as it allows another user to access all the routes and make changes to any user if given the correct routes (which includes ids).The routes work by id which is in the params. The user's id is also integrated in the token's payload.

How can I make it such that each user can access his own routes and not the other users' routes?

Comment: Routing generally happens before access control checks, hence all users are typically able to "access all routes" (but not perform each action in the route set). If you wish to restrict access by user id in addition to token, verify both in your actions/pre-action callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

ok let's look at an example

if my user trying to access his own posts `/post:id` the route should be like this and `id` is sent as a query param with the request, But if you don't wanna do it like that
then let's say the user is already sending the token to `/posts` and he is making a request to that
then

```
router.get('/posts',(req,res)=>){
  //verfiy the token 
  //if the token is valid cont // else send(403)
  // get the userID from it 
  res.redirect('/posts/<userId>);
}
```